# How can I list only Rake tasks that belong to my Rails app (without unmaintainable grep statements)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, rake

Any mature Rails app can have a lot of rake tasks:

- The tasks that ship with Rails itself.
- Tasks that are included in various gems that the app uses.
- Tasks that have been written as part of the app.

I need a way to list *only the tasks that were written as part of my app* and ignore everything that is included in Rails itself or a gem we are using.

Of course I can string a long chain of `grep -v` statements after `rake -T`, but this is a pain in the neck.

I could wrap that command in a function, but of course that goes out of date as soon as a new task is added by a new gem or a new version of Rails.  It also presumes that I won't add any tasks which use in their names any of the strings that I'm filtering out.  So I would have to always keep the function in mind when I create new rake tasks.  So it's kludgey for many reasons.

How can I get ***Rails*** to give me the information I want?

(It is the path to insanity to try to use the shell to do anything more than issue the command.  The shell does not have access to any information about where a rake task comes from.  Rails almost certainly does, or can be made to figure that out.)

Comment: You can list the rake tasks defined in a  rakefile using `rake -T -f lib/tasks/foo.rake`. So maybe you can loop through all the rakefiles in `lib/tasks` and get their tasks using `rake -T -f ...`

Comment: @iconoclast I really think it's best to namespace your apps rake tasks, so the grep filter becomes trivial.

Comment: @LesNightingill this would require rewriting all of my app's rake tasks to belong to a single top-level namespace.  Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: @iconoclast yes, I'm afraid that is what I'm suggesting. It should have been done right from the beginning of the project. Now you have to go back and redo all the tasks. If this is a daunting task, it may be possible to write a script to do it.

Comment: My hesitation is not related to the task being daunting, but  the fact that I don't feel that's an ideal way to group tasks (although it does solve this immediate problem).  I feel that the _source_ of the task (gem, rails, or my app) should be completely orthogonal to the namespace it belongs to.  If I create a task related to the database, it would make sense to put it in the `db` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

if you want load in production console terminal and run any task then you run these command

```
require 'rake' 
Rails.application.load_tasks
Rake::Task['my_task'].invoke
```